Implement a setting provider with jetpack compose and data store
I want to store my app settings in a datastore and make it easily accessible from anywhere.
For example to have an ui settings category and being able to access it and set it easily from anywhere while recomposing different parts of the UI on configuration change.
I'm currently using a library "compose-remember-preference" to implement this, but I have to copy paste the rememberXPreference each time I need it and it will retrieve the preference each time a new Composable that uses it it's composed/re-composed.
Is there a better way to handle this?
https://github.com/burnoo/compose-remember-preference
Here's an example on how i'm using it in 2 places:

@Composable
fun R2DroidTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    val isSystemDarkMode = isSystemInDarkTheme()

    var defaultColorTuple = rememberStringPreference(
        keyName = "ui.color_tuple", initialValue = colorTupleToJson(ColorTuples["Latte"]!!), defaultValue = colorTupleToJson(ColorTuples["Latte"]!!)
    )

    val (defaultContrast, setdefaultContrast) = rememberFloatPreference(keyName = "color.contrast_level", initialValue = 0.5f, defaultValue = 0.5f)
    var (darkMode, setDarkMode) = rememberIntPreference(keyName = "ui.dark", initialValue = DarkMode.SYSTEM.value, defaultValue = DarkMode.SYSTEM.value )
    var (amoled, setAmoled) = rememberBooleanPreference(keyName = "ui.amoled", initialValue = false, defaultValue = false)
    var (materialYou, setMaterialYou) = rememberBooleanPreference(keyName = "ui.material_you", initialValue = false, defaultValue = false)
    var (invertColor, setInvertColor) = rememberBooleanPreference(keyName = "color.inverted", initialValue = false, defaultValue = false)



    val state = rememberDynamicThemeState(initialColorTuple = jsonToColorTuple(defaultColorTuple.value))

    var dark by remember { mutableStateOf(isSystemDarkMode) }

    when (darkMode) {
        DarkMode.SYSTEM.value -> dark = isSystemDarkMode
        DarkMode.LIGHT.value -> dark = false
        DarkMode.DARK.value -> dark = true
    }
    MyTheme(
        state = state,
        defaultColorTuple = jsonToColorTuple(defaultColorTuple.value),
        dynamicColor = materialYou,
        amoledMode = amoled,
        isDarkTheme = dark,
        contrastLevel = defaultContrast.toDouble(),
        style = PaletteStyle.TonalSpot,
        isInvertColors = invertColor,
        content = content,
    )
}

@Composable
fun ColorTuplePreference(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, colorTuples: MutableMap<String, ColorTuple> = ColorTuples) {

    val value = rememberStringPreference(
        keyName = "ui.color_tuple", initialValue = colorTupleToJson(
            ColorTuples["Latte"]!!
        ), defaultValue = colorTupleToJson(ColorTuples["Latte"]!!)
    )
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        
        PreferenceCard(title = "foo", enabled = false, darkenOnDisable = false, modifier = modifier) {
            LazyRow(
                modifier = Modifier,
            ) {
                items(colorTuples.keys.toList()) { key ->
                    val colorTuple = ColorTuples[key]
                    colorTuple?.let {
                        ColorTuplePreview(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 4.dp),
                            onClick = { value.value = colorTupleToJson(colorTuple) },
                            colorTuple = colorTuple,
                            selected = colorTuple == jsonToColorTuple(value.value)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



Did you find a solution to your problem? I'm using CompositionLocal (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/compositionlocal#creating)
Something like so:
data class Settings(val some: Int? = null)
internal val LocalSettings = compositionLocalOf { Settings() }

fun Fragment.composeView(content: @Composable () -> Unit): ComposeView {
    val settingsViewModel = get<SettingsViewModel>() // here injected by koin
    settingsViewModel.init() // <- launch and extract values from datastore/flow

    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            val settings = remember(settingsViewModel.some) { Settings(settingsViewModel.some) }

            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalSettings provides settings) {
                MaterialTheme {
                    content()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Then value can be use in the hierarchy:
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) = composeView {
        val some = LocalSettings.current.some

        Text(some)
    }

